# Mixpanel UUID Retrieving

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, mixpanel, ios9.1

I have to retrieve UUID of user from mix panel, The expected scenario, need to append inviter UUID to their invited user events.

And how to perform increment feature for people properties in mix panel?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you read Mixpanel's [documentation](https://mixpanel.com/help/reference)?

Answer (score 0):

Mixpanel's unique identifier is called distinct_id.User can be identified by its Unique identifier as well using "distinctId" property you can retrieve user's identifier.

```
Mixpanel *mixpanel = [Mixpanel sharedInstanceWithToken:@"Token"];
[mixpanel identify:mixpanel.distinctId];
```

Same way we can access .distinctId property to retrive user details.

People property increments with no of people follow the same event.

`[mixpanel.people increment:@"Event Name" by:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];`